# Replace matching elements in array using regular expressions: invalid character

Tags: javascript

```
var input = [paul, Paula, george];
  var newReg = \paula?\i
for(var text in input) {
    if (newReg.test(text) == true) {
         input[input.indexOf(text)] = george
       }
    }

console.log(input)
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code. it should change paul and Paula to george but when I run it it says there's an illegal character

Comment: It's slash, not backslash, e.g. `/paula?/i`

Comment: Also, your values inside of `input`, and `george`, aren't wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Also, you are using for/in so your `text` variable (which you're passing to `.test`) will be the index in the array, not the value pointed to by the index.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash (\) is an *escape* character in Javascript (along with a lot of other C-like languages). This means that when Javascript encounters a backslash, it tries to escape the following character. For instance, \n is a newline character (rather than a backslash followed by the letter n).

So, thats what is causing your error, you need to replace `\paula?\i` with `/paula?/i`

Comment: This is true, but there are also _many_ other issues in the OP's given code.

Comment: He says his error is because of an illegal character. I believe this will fix that specific error. (although many others might pop up after this fix)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `\` by `/` in your regexp pattern.

You should wrap the strings inside quotes `"`

You need to match correctly your array, `val` is just the index of the word, not the word himself.

```
var input = ["paul", "Paula", "george"];
var newReg = /paula?/i;
for (var val in input) {
    if (newReg.test(input[val]) == true) {
         input[input.indexOf(input[val])] = "george";
    }
}
console.log(input);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/f163t8gz/1/)

Comment: Just a thought: In the very limited example given by the OP, `.replace` would act identically. It may be, however, that the OP actually wants to replace the entirety of any value which passes the test.

Comment: @JAAulde Thanks you're right, I've just updated my answer